# Find and replace certain texts in file using python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following textfile:

```
1-   VERSION_CONTROL {
2-   FILE_NAME = "foo.cmp";
3-   REVISION = "";
4-   AUTHOR = "doo";
5-   DATE = "Date: ";
6-   }
7-   
8-   CVTS {
9-   CVTLIST = {
10-   {
11-   CVT = "foo";
12-   }
13-   }
14-   }
15-   IFREAL {
16-   LOADLIST = "";
17-   UNLOADLIST = "";
18-   IOMAPLIST = {
19-   }
20-   }
21-   IFSIM {
22-   SIMULATIONS = {
23-   SIMULATION {
24-   NAME = "";
25-   PROGRAM = "foo.zip";
26-   
27-   RATE = "1";
28-  OFFSET = "0";
29-   SUBFRAME = "0";
30-   LENGTH = "1";
31-   ARGUMENTS = "";
32-   OPTIONS = "RT";
33-   LOOPS = "1";
34-   cpumask = "0";
35-   }
36-   }
37-   LOADLIST = "";
38-   UNLOADLIST = "";
39-   }
40-
```

I'm trying to replace the variable `LOADLIST = "";` with `LOADLIST = "init";`However, only on line  37.
My solution so far:

```
reading_file = open(myFile.txt,"r") 
               
               new_file_content = ""
               for line in reading_file:
                   stripped_line = line.strip()
                   new_line = stripped_line.replace('LOADLIST = "";', 'LOADLIST = "initScwss";')
                   new_file_content += new_line +"\n"
               reading_file.close()

               writing_file = open(entry, "w")
               writing_file.write(new_file_content)
               writing_file.close()
```

The problem with my code is that it fills the `LOADLIST` everywhere it finds which means in lines `16,17, 37 & 38`.

**Any idea how to filter the search such that only the line `37` is considered?**
Thanks in advance

Comment: use enumerate to count for line num.

Comment: `for i, line in enumerate(reading_file): if i == 36: ....`

Comment: While LOADLIST is at line 37 right now, it's actually a property of IFSIM. So, a better solution would be to parse the file and find IFSIM.LOADLIST, regardless of which line it was at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you can't change your txt file to json, if you are looking to only change the LOADLIST that comes after IFSIM, you could use a state to check that the loop has reached IFSIM.

```
entry = "outfile.txt"

reading_file = open("myFile.txt","r")

new_file_content = ""
isIfsim = False
for line in reading_file:
    stripped_line = line.strip()
    if "IFSIM" in stripped_line:
        isIfsim = True
    if isIfsim:
        if 'LOADLIST = "";' in stripped_line:
            new_line = stripped_line.replace('LOADLIST = "";', 'LOADLIST = "init";')
            new_file_content += new_line +"\n"
            isIfsim = False
        else:
            new_file_content += stripped_line +"\n"
    else:
        new_file_content += stripped_line +"\n"
reading_file.close()

writing_file = open(entry, "w")
writing_file.write(new_file_content)
writing_file.close()
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. would be glad for a vote up ^  ^

Comment: can you please shortly explain what does state-fullness mean? i've googled it however didn't find anything

Comment: @Khaled A program that is designed to remember preceding events or user interactions. In this case, the preceding event is that we reached IFSIM.

Comment: I should just say "a state."